Can a Goblin pilot use Black Thumb Rodeo on the mech their Goblin is attached to at Rank 2?
Goblin Frame has an ability called Symbiosis which reads as such

Your mech retracts its major systems and attaches itself to another mech, becoming more like a vestigial blister than a separate entity. The host must be an allied and willing mech not already hosting another Goblin, larger than and adjacent to you. While attached, you occupy their space, move with them, and benefit from hard cover, but can still be attacked and targeted separately. You also take any conditions and heat taken by your host.
Your host may use your Systems, E-Defense, and Tech Attack instead of their own. Additionally, from the beginning of the next round, you no longer take your own turns; instead, you can take two quick actions or one full action at any point during your host’s turn. You can’t Overcharge or move, but may still take reactions and free actions normally. Your host’s turn counts as your turn for the purpose of effects that refer to the start or end of a character’s turn.
This effect lasts either for the rest of the scene, until you detach as a quick action, or until you or your host becomes Stunned. When the effect ends, you don’t take a turn until the next round.

Under normal circumstances Black Thumb Rodeo requires Rodeo Master(Rank 3) to allow the pilot to effect adjacent mechs with Rodeo(Rank 2) reading as such

As a protocol, you give up the controls, pop the hatch on your mech and partly climb out, starting a BLACK THUMB RODEO and gaining a personal shield (as above). While in rodeo, your pilot is immune to involuntary movement, occupies your mech’s space and moves when it moves. This does not count as DISMOUNT and the mech can’t be controlled from outside, so it will idle unless it is capable of acting independently (e.g., if it has an NHP that has been given control, which you can do as part of this protocol).
While in rodeo, your pilot becomes a valid target and can take damage normally. If you lose your personal shield for any reason, you are immediately forced back inside your mech, ending the effect, and you cannot start a rodeo again on your following turn. You can also end a rodeo as a quick action on any of your turns.
While in rodeo, your pilot can only take the Extinguish, Field Repair, or Rig Vents actions granted by Black Thumb.

and Rodeo Master(Rank 3) reading as such

Your Black Thumb actions can be used on adjacent allied mechs.

Given Symbiosis ability results in two mechs being directly connected to each other can Black Thumb Rodeo's effects be used on the attached mech at rank 2 or does it require rank 3?

Black Thumb rank 2 is arguably less useful on a symbiotic Goblin.
So your Goblin's attached, you're out there doing active maintenance, you get caught in a blast and your personal shield takes the hit, where do you go?
Your Goblin, right? Not the mech it's attached to?
You share turns with the mech your Goblin is attached to, but that doesn't make it your mech.
It's arguable if you can even clear statuses on your own Goblin if the host mech suffered them and they came over with Symbiosis, because Black Thumb Rodeo doesn't work on self-inflicted conditions and your Goblin has those conditions as a result of Symbiosis, its own power.
